# call a db2 stored procedure from zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, stored-procedures, db2, zend-db

I recently start playing with stored procedures for db2(one day ago) and I manage to create very simple SP that worked fine when I tested them in the iAccess Navigator. Now Im trying to call the SP from my model but Im getting errors back and Im not sure how to get the return variable. Here is some code

here is my SP

```
drop procedure schema.test_ac ;
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.test_ac (IN a int, in b int, out c int)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    set c=b+a;
END;
```

here is the php code

```
public function storePro(){
    $queryStr = "call test_ac (1,1,?)";

        $stmt = $this->db->query($queryStr);
        print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
}
```

any help will be nice Thank you

Comment: what is the error message? I think you should use $this->_db instead of $this->db

Comment: this is the value of db `$this->db=Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();` 
and this is the exception Zend_Db_Statement_Db2_Exception #256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_Db may have an issue when handling DB2 stored procedures. I'll try to get that fixed in ZF 2.0. However, today you can run your example successfully using the base ibm_db2 driver functions. I tested this on a v7.1 IBM i system:

```
// get actual db2 resource from ZF object
$dbConn = $this->db->getConnection();

if (!$dbConn) {
    die("could not get connection");
}

$queryStr = "call test_ac (?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = db2_prepare($dbConn, $queryStr);

if (!$stmt) {
    die ("Could not prepare statement. " . db2_stmt_error());
}

// set values to be bound. All three variables must be created.
$in1 = 1;
$in2 = 2;
$out1 = 0; // irrelevant but must provide

db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, "in1", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, "in2", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 3, "out1", DB2_PARAM_OUT);

$result = db2_execute($stmt);

if ($result) {
    // success!
    echo "value of output var: $out1";

} else {

    die("Execute failed: " . db2_stmt_error($stmt));
}
```